# Handling WatchService events

Tags: java, multithreading, io, watch

I am trying to implement a program which would monitor folder with the files and process them.

The problem is that I am using the WatchService to monitor folders while I am adding\deleting\modify files in the folder, the WatchKey returns the list with 3 events (create, modify, delete) and the program can't execute right.

For example

I have 2 files and when I create a 3rd file my program starts

I try to handle only the ENTRY_CREATE event with switch, but it handles all 3 events.

Where I am I going wrong?

```
iC.setFolder();
        Path path = Paths.get(iC.getFolder());
        File inputFiles;
        WatchService watchService = null;
        try {
            watchService = path.getFileSystem().newWatchService();
            path.register(watchService,
                    StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE,
                    StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE,
                    StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (;;) {
            WatchKey key = null;
            try {
                key = watchService.take();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (WatchEvent event : key.pollEvents()) {
                switch (event.kind().name()) {
                    case "OVERFLOW":
                        System.out.println("We have lost some events");
                        break;
                    case "ENTRY_CREATE":
                        System.out.println("Some files created");
                        inputFiles = new File(iC.getFolder());
                        iC.processFiles(inputFiles);
                        execution.execute(iC.getQueue());
                        break;
                    case "ENTRY_DELETE":
                        System.out.println("Some files deleted");
                        inputFiles = new File(iC.getFolder());
                        iC.processFiles(inputFiles);
                        execution.execute(iC.getQueue());
                        break;
                    case "ENTRY_MODIFY":
                        System.out.println("Some files modified");
                        inputFiles = new File(iC.getFolder());
                        iC.processFiles(inputFiles);
                        execution.execute(iC.getQueue());
                        break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: I think you are doing something wrong, just use the example in this article: http://www.baeldung.com/java-nio2-watchservice

Comment: why are you creating for each event a `new File()` of a directory? that's seems a bit wrong. something like this would be fine `WatchEvent<Path> ev = (WatchEvent<Path>)event;
        Path filename = ev.context();
`

Comment: Thank you for quick answer, now it's work.